# math expression for a bounded function

Tags: function, math, expression, piecewise

I have a bounded function.

`When x > 1, y = 1;`

`when 0 <= x <= 1, y = x;`

`when x < 0, y = 0.`

Does anyone know any simple math function to represent y (Do not use piece-wise function).

For example, Heaviside function is a similar approach.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be off-topic, as it is about mathematics rather than programming. math.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: That said, if you want to know how to accomplish this in any programming language, we can easily demonstrate that. ;)

Comment: Is a two-argument `min()` and `max()` function acceptable? `y = max(0, min(x, 1))`...

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - pure math function:

[image: formula]